# Force Task URL to Open in IE

Tags: tasks, url, hyperlink, internet-explorer, browsers

Is there a way to force a URL to open in a specific browser (Internet Explorer)?  We have some people using chrome for their email, but I lose some of my task functionality if they open the email link in chrome.

I was able to find that you can use the following if you create a shortcut, but what about just a hyperlink?  It doesn't seem to work for me.

“C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe” http://url_you_want

I am hearing from our IT/IM group that this is impossible...thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought - So you are basically forcing the launch of a .exe file on the clients machine to load your file. In your case , you want your chrome to identify that this url needs IE to run .  See it the chrome extensions can help you with this ( http://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-documentation ) .

Comment: We have the IE tab, and that doesn't seem to work.  The only way it works now is if we copy the link address from the email and paste it into an open IE browser.  I want to bypass that step altogether and just force the link to open a new IE browser if possible.